# Code Explorer for Two files

Tags: java

Is there a website that I can put in two pieces of Java codes and see which lines are missing from one another?

Comment: A diff tool should give you the response. Such free tools exist for every OS (WinMerge, diff, kdiff, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a '[diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)' tool.

One example:
http://www.quickdiff.com/

If you are in a *NIX platform, the `diff` program should be already available to you.

Just do:

```
diff file1 file2
```

and it should output the difference between the two files

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.quickdiff.com/.

I don't know how it works but appears to be nice online tool.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try [Line Diff](http://linediff.com/). it takes two code/text snippets generates a diff and renders is just like github.